# why the list of pages does not appear in my categories pages (mediawiki)?

Tags: docker, mediawiki

This page : https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Categories

State that :
Each of the pages in the Category namespace represents a so-called category, a grouping of related pages, and contains an index for the pages of its category.

Mine do not !

If I add a  `[[Category:mycat]]` in an article and save it, mycat appear in the category list widget.
But if I clic the link and create the new category page, I do not have any article list.

Do I Forget something ?

I am on the "latest" library/mediawiki docker image, with the "timeless" skin and a sqllite database.

Comment: Either you are not processing the jobs in your [job queue](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Job_queue), or maybe they are erroring out. Check with [`showJobs.php`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:ShowJobs.php).

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what was the problem, but the last Docker image version work out of the box ...